# What do I do with all my gold?

Tags: pillars-of-eternity

I have played roughly 50h and not yet finished. I have tons of money and don't know how to use it or in what. I always sleep in the most expensive inns etc...

And the loot I get is always better than what the blacksmith offers. I already upgraded my stronghold to the max.

Is there some investment I have missed?

I have more than 60k...

Comment: I think the economy mechanism is a kind of broken. Each time you collect several hundred cp of money(with a large part lost to bandits), and use 200 cp to pay off any unwelcome guest. which is quite a joke compared to the large amount of money you already have mid-game.

Comment: You can enchant weapons and armour, make scrolls and potions - all this costs quite a bit. Also many things you can buy are quite good and expensive.

Comment: Maybe the Gold amount is fixed for a higher difficulty, where consumables are needed in higher quantities. I just remembering how a friend and I played BG and you have much gold but the higher consumables like spell disrupting arrows cost like 1k each piece.

Answer (score 1):

Several players report the same "issue": this game lacks a real money sink, mid to end-game. They found some ways of using all their gold amounts:

- by buying and crafting supplies

> Crafting supplies can get a little pricey if you decide to clean out
>   an entire shop's supplies. Build up enough of a supply and you can get
>   some nice enchants and potions.

([Source on Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/projecteternity/comments/31jx7j/what_can_i_spend_my_money_on/cq2fl1m/))

- by enchanting weapons

> [...] enchant your weapons they cost gold too

([Source on GOG Forums](https://www.gog.com/forum/pillars_of_eternity/what_to_spend_gold_on))